# AVPlayer seeking a HLS Audio Stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm using AVPlayer to stream a hls stream. **The issue** I'm having is that I'm incapable of seeking to a time.

The seeking logic works fine with the [Apple's example hls stream](http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8). It also works fine with the non-hls stream I have but we wanted to use hls on this project.

**So my belief** is that problem is more likely with our stream and how AVPlayer handles it.

The playlist.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=61378,CODECS="mp4a.40.34"
chunklist_w1105403169.m3u8
```

The chunklist_w1105403169.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:5015
#EXTINF:10.028,
media_w1105403169_5015.mp3
#EXTINF:10.036,
media_w1105403169_5016.mp3
#EXTINF:10.027,
media_w1105403169_5017.mp3
```

I have checked the stream using mediastreamvalidator and I do get:

```
Warning: (0:-16230) #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE should only be in master playlist
```

but its my understanding Apple ignores this flag.

I've no control over the stream but can request changes.

**A cut down version of my implementation:**

Setup of the player

```
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

Seeking back by x seconds

```
- (void)trySeekBackBy:(NSTimeInterval )seconds
     CMTime minus = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, 1);
     CMTime time = CMTimeSubtract(self.currentTime, minus);

     //check that time is within the seek able range. 
     if ([self canSeekToTime:time]) {
           //I normally just seekToTime: 
          [self seekToTime:time toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
     }
   / /else work down till we can find a range we can seek to 
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried with an Apple sample HLS stream? No reason why HLS shouldn't seek properly. You should be creating the `minus` value using `NSEC_PER_SEC` as the timescale though.